# globalToLocal convertPoint in android

Tags: android, android-layout

In iOS - you can do something like this:

```
CGPoint globalPoint = [someView convertPoint:point fromView:self];
```

This give you a point from some view in the reference frame of another view.

What is the equivalent for this in Android?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to cater for the respective scroll offsets?

So assuming you're using a basic Point class, with floats `x`, `y`, you could have a helper function:

```
public static Point convertPoint(View view, Point point, View fromView) {
  return new Point(view.getScrollX() + point.x - fromView.getScrollX(), 
                   view.getScrollY() + point.y - fromView.getScrollY());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle transforms such as TranslationX, TranslationY, ScaleX and ScaleY.